# Run a cron job (or similar) in the background of WP after post update/create

Tags: wp-cron

I would like to run a filter on post content after it has been created or updated.

I would like this to occur after the user has submitted the post, as it may be a bit of a lengthy process (a find/replace to search for glossary terms and replace them with links).

What's the most efficient and reliable way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does this have to occur immediately on publish? Or could it occur...say...once every hour or something like that?

Comment: That would be absolutely fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's some code I just whipped up. Completely untested, just wrote it right off the cuff...so don't expect it to work 100% when you drop it in, but the core concept is there, as is a decent amount of the legwork

```
add_action( 'my_filter_posts_content', 'my_filter_content' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_set_content_filter' );

if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_filter_posts_content' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_filter_posts_content' );
}

function my_filter_content() {
    //check to see if posts need to be parsed
    if( get_option( 'my_updated_posts' ) == false )
        return false;

    //parse posts
    $ids = unserialize( get_option( 'my_updated_posts' ) );
    foreach( $ids as $v ) {
        YOUR_FUNCTION_HERE( $v );
    }

    //make sure no values have been added while loop was running
    $id_recheck = unserialize( get_option( 'my_updated_posts' ) );
    my_close_out_filter( $ids, $id_recheck );

    /*
    once all options, including any added during the running of what
    could be a long cronjob are done, remove the value and close out
    */
    delete_option( 'my_updated_posts' );
    return true;
}

function my_set_content_filter( $post_id ) {
    //get the previous value
    $ids = unserialize( get_option( 'my_updated_posts' ) );

    //add new value if necessary
    if( !in_array( $post_id, $ids ) ) {
        $ids[] = $post_id;
        update_option( 'my_updated_posts', serialize( $ids ) );
    }
}

function my_close_out_filter( $beginning_array, $end_array ) {
    $diff = array_diff( $beginning_array, $end_array );
    if( !empty ( $diff ) ) {
        foreach( $diff as $v ) {
            YOUR_FUNCTION_HERE( $v );
        }
    }
    my_close_out_filter( $end_array, unserialize( get_option( 'my_updated_posts' ) ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll give it a go now. Is `YOUR_FUNCTION_HERE( $v );` where I'd put my filtering code?

Comment: Yup, you've got it...let me know how that works, I'm interested as to what stupid error(s) I made :D

Comment: You know...thinking about it, I bet you could do some pretty powerful filtering if you based a class off that code...

Comment: One thing.. how do I go about seeing whether or not the cron job has actually been scheduled?

Comment: There are plugins that will do that for you, I think Cron View is the one that I use, but I cannot remember.

Comment: OK. It's breaking on this line: `if ( !empty( get_option( 'my_updated_posts' ) ) )` in `my_filter_content`. My server is set up so that errors aren't publicly displayed though, so I'm not sure why!

Comment: Removing the `empty` seems to have worked - `get_option` apparently returns `FALSE` if there are no entries with that name. Is this OK?

Comment: Yup, that should be good, `get_option( 'my_updated_posts' ) == false )` should do it for you, it shouldn't have been a negative on that `empty()` anyways, that was a brain fart...I'm pretty pleased that that was all I messed up!

Comment: Yeah, I think everything else is working - I can see the cron in `Cron View` and the option is being set. The filter isn't working but I suspect that's my issue rather than yours :) Thanks very much!

Comment: Have it do something simple to test it, like add [updated] to the post name or something like that. You can change the interval it acts at too, that's talked about [here](http://wpengineer.com/1908/use-wordpress-cron/)

Comment: Thanks for everything. New post here if you're interested... :D http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42814/running-a-function-on-post-content-and-cpt-meta

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37647/4793). It's a proof-of-concept for running a native crontab in Linux with your WP installation.

As for WP-Cron functionality, beware of these caveats:

- WP-Cron is a pseudo cron that is runs when WP is loaded. WP checks if a WP-Cron is scheduled or behind schedule to run and then executes the cron script.
- If there is not adequate traffic, your cron might run really late.
- Scheduling a WP-Cron to run during peak hours might cause some performance issues if it's a large, intensive script.

If you choose to go the WP-Cron route, [here's a great article](http://wpengineer.com/1908/use-wordpress-cron/) to show you how to use it. You can also check out the WP functions in the Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WP-Cron_Functions).

I prefer the reliability of a Linux crontab, especially for integral, heavy-weight cron scripts. For extremely lightweight scripts, I do use WP-Cron at times.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Brian. I was under the impression that WP had built-in features for setting up cron jobs?

Comment: Well, it's a psuedo-cron which depends on people visiting your site. It could create a performance issue for the unlucky user who hits your site when it's time to run the wp-cron. The more reliable approach to make sure the cron runs at scheduled intervals is to use crontab. You can see the wp-cron functions here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WP-Cron_Functions

Comment: Thanks Brian. Site gets enough traffic (30,000 unique visitors/week) so I think we'll be OK in those terms. The script isn't absolutely massive and there'll very rarely be more than one post at a time updated.

Answer (score 0):

Would the save_post action work for you?

```
<?php
add_action( 'save_post', 'wp_save_post' );
function wp_save_post()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

You might also consider edit_post or publish_post

You can view other actions in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Post.2C_Page.2C_Attachment.2C_and_Category_Actions_.28Admin.29)

Comment: Hi Kyle. Thanks, I understand the workings of `save_post` :) What I'm trying to do is run this filter in the **background**. If I run the filter on `save_post`, it'll take quite some time for the post to save, which is an annoyance for my authors that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Didn't realize the background requirement.