# Running a function on post content and CPT meta

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-cron

As per [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42694/run-a-cron-job-or-similar-in-the-background-of-wp-after-post-update-create) thread I'm scheduling a `wp_cron` every hour which runs a function. The function I'm running is reasonably lengthy and I didn't want authors to have to deal with the waiting times.

My question is this - when creating a function which runs from the following code (`$ids` is a list of post IDs):

```
$ids = unserialize( get_option( 'my_updated_posts' ) );
foreach( $ids as $v ) {
    YOUR_FUNCTION_HERE( $v );
}
```

How do I **a)** retrieve content if the `id` relates to a `Post` type and then update it, or **b)** update meta fields if said `id` is actually a `species` Custom Post Type?

For **b)**, will I have to update each meta field individually or is there a filter I can apply?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would filter which posts go into the option, that's light enough processing that it can be done on that end.

To get the content of the post you can use `get_post( $v );`.

To get the metavalues for the post you can use `get_post_custom( $v );`.

To update the meta values you will use `update_post_meta()`. You will have to do these individually.